# Is there a way to install a trigger after slack app installation?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I'm creating an app using the future/beta/modular/new/next-gen Slack platform https://api.slack.com/future

I'm looking for a way to install a trigger as part of the installation process. I've looked through the documentation and I don't see any way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A trigger can only be created after an app is, either running locally (via `slack run`), or has been deployed in prod (via `slack deploy`). Triggers are created with the `slack trigger create` command via the CLI.